# submit arrive no picture at all

Tags: html, css

it is such that I must have a picture on the submit button, but it does not appear on it at all.

I would like that it came to resemble something like this:

[image]

now see my like this, and I can not understand why it does not appear on the page.

[image]

Html

```
<div id="sogbar">
<input type="submit" name="sognu" class="sognu">
<div class="cl"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#sognu {
    background: url('/img/sogindhold/sognu.png') no-repeat;
    float: right;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#e4d24a,#dec83d);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e4d24a,#dec83d);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#e4d24a,#dec83d);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#e4d24a,#dec83d);
    background: linear-gradient(#e4d24a,#dec83d);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    border: 1px solid #2a2c0f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 75px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#sognu:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about how you are trying to achieve this<s>, but if you want to display the icon on `#sognu` element.</s>

Seems you are targeting a wrong element, If you want to apply these declarations to the `input` element, you should use a leading period `.` to select the element by its class name.

I.e. change `#sognu` to `.sognu`

Then you could use multiple values for `background` property as follows:

```css
.sognu {
    float: right;
    background: url('/img/sogindhold/sognu.png') 50% 50% no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(#e4d24a,#dec83d);
    background: url('/img/sogindhold/sognu.png') 50% 50% no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(#e4d24a,#dec83d);
    background: url('/img/sogindhold/sognu.png') 50% 50% no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(#e4d24a,#dec83d);
    background: url('/img/sogindhold/sognu.png') 50% 50% no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(#e4d24a,#dec83d);
    background: url('/img/sogindhold/sognu.png') 50% 50% no-repeat, linear-gradient(#e4d24a,#dec83d);

    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    border: 1px solid #2a2c0f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 75px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: it help me a lot, but now the picture is just too big in the background to submit, what can I do there?

Comment: @Jesperbook First of all make sure that you want to apply the background image on `#sognu`. However you could use [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property to change the size of the image.

Comment: it works still under construction. it appears only half. and i have try its new code u have make,

Comment: @Jesperbook Have you changed `#sognu` to `.sognu`?

Comment: @Jesperbook Seems the icon of *Magnifying glass* is so big, ain't it? If so, better to reduce its dimensions via an image editor. You could also resize the background image by `background-size` property as I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for help, i have make its on photoshop to it size.

Comment: @Jesperbook You are welcome. By any chance if you needed the `background-size`, you could use that as follows: `background: url('path/to/image.png') 50% 50% / 10% 10% no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(#e4d24a,#dec83d);`. background size value: `10% 10%` is separated by a forward slash `/`. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ZNsbU/162/).

Answer (score 0):

you are using ID `#sognu` in your css style, But in HTML you caliing class `.sognu`.